# React native changing instance prop not rerender component

Tags: react-native, react-redux, components, render, mapstatetoprops

I have an entity class called `order`

```js
const order = new Order({status: 'available'});
```

```js
export default class Order {
  constructor({status}) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  isCanceled() {
    return this.status === CANCELED;
  }
}
```

when passing `order` to a component throw `mapStateToProps`
when the status changes. `mapStateToProps` will be called again with the new status but the component will not be rendered with the new data

but if I passed the `order` as a standard object it will re-render with the new data

This code is not working

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  const order = new Order({status: 'available'});

  return {
    order,
  };
};
```

This code works

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  const order = new Order({status: 'available'});

  return {
    order: {...order},
  };
};
```

I need the first code to work as I use some functions from the object inside the component like `isCanceled()`

Answer (score 0):

Hello all I knew what was the issue

the problem was in my reducer as I was changing in the state directly so the method wasn't pure function. So, react didn't recognize the change in props

this link has an example
[React Native components not re-render if props changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011933/react-native-components-not-re-render-if-props-changed)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this, while keeping the {...order} (2nd method you're using)

```
export default class Order {
  constructor({status}) {
    this.status = status;
    this.isCanceled = this.isCanceled; //add this line
  }

  isCanceled() {
    return this.status === CANCELED;
  }
}
```